# RAVE: Pasting images from the clipboard directly into SE

Tags: discussion

I don't have much to say other than I love the new ability to "paste" binary pictures directly into the SE editor.  This is such a time saver and is the first of it's kind I've seen.

Great programming work StackExchange folks!!

I normally don't (and have never posted) something of this nature but I wanted people to notice and or try this feature out.  It is very cool.

If slightly nagged I will quickly delete this....

Comment: do you have a link somewhere which explains how to do this? I would find this functionality very useful, but despite using Chrome I cannot see how todo it.

Comment: @RoryAlsop - Sure, just "ask a question" and in the body insert an image from the menu.  The pop-up will prompt you to paste in from the clipboard.  Just pressing ctr-v worked for me (command v on OSX)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of notes and more info

This feature is implemented using the [Clipboard API](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/clipops/) and [File API](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/). Currently, standard and semi-standard implementations only work in Chrome and IE9+. This feature **does not work in Firefox** (at least not with SE code).

[Other services](http://pasteboard.co/) got it working in Firefox. The Firefox workaround has also been [posted on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6804718/1105514).